# How to parse AWS CLI json output using jq to get array of volume-ids?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jq

I'm using the AWS CLI to get the `BlockDeviceMappings` array for a specific instance like this,

### awscli query

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=mongodb-*" "Name=private-ip-address,Values=$MEMBER_IP" \
    --output json --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*]
```

**output**

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda", 
                "Ebs": {
                    "Status": "attached", 
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                    "VolumeId": "vol-xvda-xxx", 
                    "AttachTime": "2014-10-13T14:40:13.000Z"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdb", 
                "Ebs": {
                    "Status": "attached", 
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false, 
                    "VolumeId": "vol-sdb-xxxx", 
                    "AttachTime": "2014-10-13T14:40:13.000Z"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdc", 
                "Ebs": {
                    "Status": "attached", 
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false, 
                    "VolumeId": "vol-sdc-xxx", 
                    "AttachTime": "2014-10-13T14:40:13.000Z"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdd", 
                "Ebs": {
                    "Status": "attached", 
                    "DeleteOnTermination": false, 
                    "VolumeId": "vol-sdd-xxx", 
                    "AttachTime": "2014-10-13T14:40:13.000Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

**desired output**

I want a list of the volume-ids for `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd`, respectively.

`vol-sdb-xxxxx, vol-sdc-xxxx, vol-sdd-xxxxx`

I've attempted to use `jq` to do the parsing by piping the aws-cli output to `jq`, but I keep getting "jq: error: Cannot index array with string".

Also, it's possible that the `DeviceName` might not always come in the order that I can assume that the 2nd,3rd and 4th elements in the array are in the right order, so I'd like to make sure that the desired output of volume-ids is always in the form: sdb, sdc, sdd if possible.

### update 1

After trying both of Jeff's suggestions:

**suggestion 1**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=mongodb-*" "Name=private-ip-address,Values=$MEMBER_IP" --output json --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*]" | jq 'select(.DeviceName? | test("/dev/sd[bcd]")) | .Ebs.VolumeId'
error: test is not defined
select(.DeviceName? | test("/dev/sd[bcd]")) | .Ebs.VolumeId                      1 compile error

[Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

**suggestion 2**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=mongodb-*" "Name=private-ip-address,Values=$MEMBER_IP" --output json --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*]" | jq 'select(  
         .DeviceName? as $dn
             | ["b","c","d"]
             | map($dn == "/dev/sd\(.)")
             | any
     )
   | .Ebs.VolumeId'
```

No output

I'm using jq-1.4 which I believe is the latest.

### update 2

The following works with jq-1.4,

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=mongodb-*" "Name=private-ip-address,Values=$MEMBER_IP" --output json --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*]" | jq '.. | select(.DeviceName? as $dn | ["b","c","d"] | map($dn == "/dev/sd\(.)") | any) | .Ebs.VolumeId'
```

Comment: How do you get JSON if you specify text as output? (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#text-output)

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Updated to reflect json option.

Comment: You can use the text output instead of the JSON one to simplify the parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the latest version where the `test` filter is implemented, you could do this:

```
.. | select(.DeviceName? | test("/dev/sd[bcd]")) | .Ebs.VolumeId
```

Otherwise, you'll have to make some adjustments:

```
.. | select(.DeviceName? == ("/dev/sdb","/dev/sdc","/dev/sdd")) | .Ebs.VolumeId
```

Comment: I'm using `jq-1.4` which seems to be the latest release according to the project site. I'm not getting any results from either version you've suggested. Please see my updated question for details of the commands I'm running and the error messages.

Comment: The leading `.. |` is required. You left it out in both cases. You should also leave out the added whitespace in the filter and have it all in one line. I don't know if it will work like that in the command line. It's like that for readability here. Didn't exprct you to put it in verbatim.

Comment: P.s., regular expressions are coming in the next versions. Certainly not 1.4. However 1.4.2 might have it, but the latest build should definitely have it.

Comment: Thank you the "uglier" version works great after I added `jq '.. | ' and removed the whitespace ;) Will use the nicer version when 1.4.2 is released.

Comment: I found out a much cleaner way to write that filter. The comma operator is quite handy.